# Not getting this behavior of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
  int x, y;

  x = *a + *b;
  y = abs(*a - *b);

  *a = x;
  *b = y;

}

int main() {
  int a, b;
  int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;

  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  update(pa, pb);
  printf("%d\n%d", a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is with the update function. On input `4 5` output is `9 1`.
But if I don't use `x` and `y` variable I can do this like below-

```
*a = *a + *b;
*b = abs(*a - *b);
```

But in this case, input: `4 5`

output: `9 4`

I believe output should be same. Please explain why output is different.

Comment: Single step through the program with your debugger and watch all variables.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging - you need paper and a pen. You do not need a computer

Comment: If you don't store old value of `*a` before you change it, you lose it. End of story. That is what `x` does.

Comment: Your issue is not related to pointers

Comment: What is the value of `*a` in the call to `abs(*a - *b)` in the first version vs. the second version?

Answer (score 3):

In this version

```
*a = *a + *b;
*b = abs(*a - *b);
```

The new value of `*a` is used at the line `*b = abs(*a - *b);`.

On the other hand, in this version

```
x = *a + *b;
y = abs(*a - *b);

*a = x;
*b = y;
```

Both calculation uses the original values of `*a` and `*b`.

This is why the output differs.